# Console error whilst waiting for API response - React/Redux

Tags: ajax, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, render

I am fetching data from a remote API in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.fetchRemoteData('photos')
}
```

And then the received data is passed to my component props in `mapStateToProps`, using a selector to filter a specific object from the received array:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, { params }) => {
   const photoId = parseInt(params.photoId)
   return {
      singlePhoto: getSinglePhoto(state.filteredList.photos.jsonArray, photoId),
      isFetching: state.filteredList.photos.isFetching
   }
}
```

The content renders, but there is a split second before that, where it seems to be trying to the render the content before the data is successfully retrieved, which brings up the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
```

`undefined` is here referring to `this.props.singlePhoto`. But when singlePhoto receives the data payload the content renders.

Here is my **container** component:

```
class PhotoSingle extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fetchRemoteData('photos')
   }
   render() {
      const {singlePhoto, isFetching} = this.props
      const photoTitle = capitalizeFirstLetter(singlePhoto.title)
      return (
         <div>
            <PhotoSingleImg singlePhoto={singlePhoto} photoTitle={photoTitle} isFetching={isFetching}/>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, { params }) => {
   const photoId = parseInt(params.photoId)
   return {
      singlePhoto: getSinglePhoto(state.filteredList.photos.jsonArray, photoId),
      isFetching: state.filteredList.photos.isFetching
   }
}
import * as actions from '../actions/actionCreators'

PhotoSingle = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(PhotoSingle)

export default PhotoSingle;
```

And my **presentational** component:

```
const PhotoSingleImg = ({ singlePhoto, photoTitle, isFetching }) => {
   if (isFetching) {
      return <h4>Fetching data...</h4>
   }
   return (
   <div>
      <h1>Single Photo</h1>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <hr />
      <img className='single-photo' src={singlePhoto.url} />
      <p>Album ID: {singlePhoto.albumId} | Photo ID: {singlePhoto.id}</p>
   </div>
   )
}

export default PhotoSingleImg;
```

I'm unsure how to make it so the content will only attempt to render *after* I the API response has been received.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined initial state in redux store?

You can try this way:

```
return singlePhoto ? 
   (<div>
      <h1>Single Photo</h1>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <hr />
      <img className='single-photo' src={singlePhoto.url} />
      <p>Album ID: {singlePhoto.albumId} | Photo ID: {singlePhoto.id}</p>
   </div>) : null
```